# As3 checking to see if movie clips are visible when a timer runs out

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There was a very similar question posted a few years ago and that helpful answer got me part of the way to understanding, but as a newcomer to AS3, I need a little more help to get to the finish line.

Here's what's I'm trying to do:

1. I have 9 movie clips that I'm sorting. I need to be able to detect when no more items are left to be sorted.
2. I want to create a countdown timer to countdown from 30 seconds and display in a dynamic text box on the screen (I'm a total newbie; doing the below code was a huge stretch for me and even after multiple tutorials on timers, I can't get it to work. The code is commented out in my file; I deleted it from below).
3. I think I need to create an array of the items, but not sure how to do that and incorporate that into the timer code and condition statements.

I *think* it might go something like this:

```
if (time==0 && itemsToSort >0) {
      goToAndPlay (2, "Try Again!");
}
if (time==0 && itemsToSort <1){
      goToAndPlay (5, "Great job!")
      cheer.play();
}
```

I haven't yet set up an array I haven't defined yet what time and itemsToSort mean, I wasn't sure if the above would work, or where in the code below I ought to put it if it would work.

### Thanks!!!

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.Sound;

var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;
var correct:Sound = new Toss();
var incorrect:Sound = new Swoosh();
var background:Sound = new Background();

cstrawberry.buttonMode = true;
cstrawberry.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
cstrawberry.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

csandwich.buttonMode = true;
csandwich.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
csandwich.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

cnapkin.buttonMode = true;
cnapkin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
cnapkin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

rbottle.buttonMode = true;
rbottle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
rbottle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

rcup.buttonMode = true;
rcup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
rcup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

rfoil.buttonMode = true;
rfoil.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
rfoil.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

lspork.buttonMode = true;
lspork.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
lspork.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

ljuice.buttonMode = true;
ljuice.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
ljuice.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

lyogurt.buttonMode = true;
lyogurt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
lyogurt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

background.play();

function hover(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
}

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
   event.target.startDrag(true);
   event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
   objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
   objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
}
function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void {   
   event.target.stopDrag();   
   //check if the leading Letter for both Sprites is the same   
   if (testIfMatch(event.target.name, event.target.dropTarget.parent.name)){
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.visible = false;
        correct.play();
   }else{      
        event.target.x = objectoriginalX;       
        event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
        incorrect.play();       
   }
}

function testIfMatch(_drop:String, _target:String):Boolean  {   
if (_drop.substr(0, 1) == _target.substr(0, 1)) {       
    return true;        
} else{      
    return false       
}
```

}

Comment: Also, the filter drop-shadow code doest work. I wanted it to throw a shadow on mouse-over but it's not working. At one point in my code it just  doesn't work; not sure why.
    function hover(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
    }

Comment: For the button effect, if you are using the built in "button" symbol (by selecting object, press f8 and convert to "button") then you can edit the timeline of that button (by double clicking it). It will have four frames: normal, mouseover, mouse down and clicked. You can change these, and the button will then change automatically to the relevant frame (e.g. mouseover when mouse is over button) without needing code.

Comment: Still don't understand what's your main question. Please define one, so people can try to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want there to be a visual indicator of remaining time, using a `Timer` may not give you the flexibility you want.  Also, you need to register the buttons for `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events for the [DropShadow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/DropShadowFilter.html#DropShadowFilter()) to apply.

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.Sound;

var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;
var correct:Sound = new Toss();
var incorrect:Sound = new Swoosh();
var background:Sound = new Background();

// For convenience (and lookup later), we add the buttons to an array.
var btnArray = [cstrawberry, csandwich, cnapkin, rbottle, rcup, rfoil, lspork, ljuice, lyogurt];

// Loop through the array, and register each to the events we need.
for each (var button in btnArray) {
    button.buttonMode = true;
    button.addEventListener("mouseOver", buttonEvents);
    button.addEventListener("mouseOut", buttonEvents);
    button.addEventListener("mouseDown", buttonEvents);
    button.addEventListener("mouseUp", buttonEvents);
}

background.play();

function buttonEvents(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Here we handle all button states
    // Simplify references to the current button by creating a local var.
    var btn:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    switch (e.type) {
        case "mouseOver":
            // Show the dropdown.
            btn.filters = new Array(new DropShadowFilter(10, 90, 0, 0.25, 10, 10));
            break;
        case "mouseOut":
            // Hide the dropdown
            btn.filters = new Array(new DropShadowFilter(0, 90, 0, 0, 10, 10));
            break;
        case "mouseDown":
            // Drag the button and store the original locs
            btn.startDrag(true);
            btn.parent.addChild(btn);
            objectoriginalX = btn.x;
            objectoriginalY = btn.y;
            break;
        case "mouseUp":
            // Drop the drag, and evaluate if it was correct
            btn.stopDrag();   

            if (testIfMatch(btn.name, btn.dropTarget.parent.name)){
                btn.removeEventListener("mouseDown", pickupObject);
                btn.removeEventListener("mouseUp", dropObject);
                btn.buttonMode = false;
                btn.visible = false;
                correct.play();
            } else {
                btn.x = objectoriginalX; 
                btn.y = objectoriginalY;
                incorrect.play(); 
            }
            break;
    }
}

function testIfMatch(_drop:String, _target:String):Boolean {
    //check if the leading Letter for both Sprites is the same    
    if (_drop.substr(0, 1) == _target.substr(0, 1)) { 
        return true;  
    } else {
        return false ;
    }
}

// Let's create something to look at the countdown.
var countdownTime:int = 30;
var countdown:TextField = new TextField();
countdown.text = "Time: " + countdownTime;
addChild(countdown);


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateCounter);
var lastSecond:Number = flash.utils.getTimer();
function updateCounter(e:Event):void {
    var now:Number = flash.utils.getTimer();

    // If more than one second has past, reset the lastSecond to now, and update the counter.
    if (now - lastSecond > 1000) {
        lastSecond += 1000;
        countdownTime--;
        countdown.text = "Time: " + countdownTime;
        if (countdownTime < 1) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateCounter);

            // Count how many are still visible
            var visibleButtons:int = 0;
            for each (btn in btnArray) {
                if (btn.visible) {
                    visibleButtons++;
                }
            }

            if (visibleButtons > 0) {
                goToAndPlay (2, "Try Again!");
            } else {
                goToAndPlay (5, "Great job!")
                cheer.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```